# Is it possible to use TVertScrollBox in TFlowLayout for scrolling vertical in FireMonkey?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm developing a new FMX project and I needed to use **TFlowLayout**.

There is no more space for current items count. I decided to use **TVertScrollBox** but its not working on it.

Is there any way to use **TFlowLayout** with vertical scroll?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure this works fine.  To test, start a new blank FMX project, drop a TVertScrollBox on the form and drop a TFlowlayout inside the TVertScrollbox. Use the structure view to ensure that the TFlowlayout is inside the TVertscrollbox.

Now adjust the size of the TFlotlayout component and you will be able to scroll vertically even in the IDE.

I quickly tried this in Berlin 10.1 Update 2 and it works as expected.

You didn't post any code but if you are adding objects to your TFLowLayout at runtime you will need to create an AutoSize function that will adjust the height of the TFlowLayout to be large enough for all of its child objects and align the TFlowLayout to the top of the TVertScrollbox.  If you can't figure out how to implement the AutoSize function I suggest you post a separate question with some sample code.

Comment: Should I resize TFlowLayout a little bit lower? I have one TVertScrollBox in my form and its align is Client. Then I added TFlowLayout inside it and its align is Client too. I designed a custom button which has 1 TImage, 2 TRectangle and 1 TLabel in. Then I copied-pasted 4 times. Now I have 5 items on my form. I changed height of form to lower height but it doesnt work in IDE and runtime. What did I missed? I think I explained my idea clearly, am I?

Comment: The alignment of your TFlowLayout should be set to Top for the height property to have an effect. If you set it to Client then you are asking the TFlowLayout to always be the same size as the TVertScrollBox so there's no need to scroll and items that don't fit are simply not visible.

Comment: I meant there is a container that will have a lot of items in it. So I have to use almost every pixels on screen for it. If we remove header and footer bars and menu, the rest are for my TFlowLayout display. (I captured an image: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/H4wB4J0.png) Those 5 items can be increased so screen can be scrollable vertically.

Comment: At this point, without some code, I'm not sure I understand the problem. If the component layout is done as described above you should be able to grow the number of icons in your dashboard layout and they should scroll once the TFlowLayout height becomes larger than that of the TVertScrollBox - assuming that you have an 'AutoSize' or a 'Grow' function that gets called each time you add an icon/shape to the TFLowLayout.

Comment: I'm happy to help some more with some code. What you can do is right-click on the designer and select 'Show as text'. Copy the contents and paste in Stackoverflow. Alos include your 'AutoSize' function.

Comment: Thank you for your helps. I did like you said before. Align top is the point. I fixed dashboard size then I set layout height larger than this. It works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I did the same thing, I checked with your solution, but it was work for me.
I fill the FlowLayout at runtime and  FlowLayout.Align is Top

Comment: @GBg Make sure that you set the height of the TFlowLayout to a value that is more than the height of TVertScrollbox. What I do is use a helper function to add items to the TFlowLayout. The function adds the item to the TFlowLayout and also increases the height of the component depending on the combined height of all items. This way, the height of the TFlowLayout increases everytime I add something to it.

Comment: @AlainThiffault , thanks
i write this
 var c:=(Sender as TFlowLayout).Children.Count;
 if c=0 then
  Exit;
 var h:=(((Sender as TFlowLayout).Children.Items[c-1]) as TLayout).Height;
 var Y:=(((Sender as TFlowLayout).Children.Items[c-1]) as TLayout).Position.Y;
 for var I := 0 to c-1 do
 begin
  if (((Sender as TFlowLayout).Children.Items[I]) as TLayout).Position.Y>Y then
   y:=(((Sender as TFlowLayout).Children.Items[I]) as TLayout).Position.Y;
 end;
 (Sender as TFlowLayout).Height:=(((Sender as TFlowLayout).Children.Items[c-1]) as TLayout).Height+Y;

Comment: I discovered....I tested with FlowLayout and GridLayout with the same effect. The main issue is property Aligmn to TOP and second, the Height needs to be larger than VertScrollBox.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure scrolling of a FlowLayout inside the VertScrollBox set the FlowLayout.Align:=alTop
not alClient, as in this case the Height of a Flowlayout will always be binded to the height of it's Parent. All content that exceeds this height will be cutted.